# Filling in blanks in a multiplication problem knowing only the set of digits in the product and that 9 divides each factor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations

The 5774 [Ulpaniada](http://ulpaniada.macam.ac.il/english/about.asp) (part 2 of it) includes the following question:

> The following multiplication exercises uses all $9$ digits $1,2,3,\ldots,9$. The digits are encoded by asterisks. We are told that the numbers in each of the three rows are divisible by $9$, and that the answer row consists of four consecutive numbers, not necessarily in order.
>
> The sum of the last digits of the three numbers (denoted by red asterisks in the illustration) is:
>
> $$\phantom{\times*}**\color{maroon}*\\\times\underline{\phantom{**}*\color{maroon}*}\\\phantom{\times}***\color{maroon}*$$

It gave five answer choices: $21$, $20$, $19$, $18$, and $17$.

I solved it, but I am unsatisfied with my method: it required far too much trial-and-error (guess-and-check) effort and far too little insight. I'm guessing there's a neater method I'm missing; does anyone have one?

---

My method, for what it's worth:

Because the product has consecutive digits that sum to a multiple of $9$, it must have the digits $3,4,5,6$ in some order. (I assumed the question posers weren't counting $8,9,0,1$ as consecutive, since it had mentioned the "$9$ digits $1,2,3,\ldots,9$".) Since the factors are also divisible by $9$, the product is divisible by $81$; since there's only one $5$ in the multiplication problem, it can't be the last digit of the product. So we're looking for a product with the digits $3,4,5,6$ (not $5$ last), a multiple of $81$.

From there, I decided to guess and check mutliples of $81$. The first mutiple of $81$ I found was $4536$. It's $2^33^47$; choosing a $2$-digit product of some of those primes to serve as a possible $2$-digit factor in the multiplication problem shows that none actually works.

I then decided that that method takes too long, so tried to use the five given answer choices to eliminate possibilities, as follows. The product must end with $3$, $4$, or $6$. If it ends with $4$, then its factors must end with $2$ and $7$; if with $3$, then $7$ and $9$; if with $6$, then $2$ and $8$ or $7$ and $8$. The last three possibilities give last-digit sums among the five answer choices. I then went through the permutations of $3456$ ending in $3$ or $6$ (there are, of course, only $12$ such) to determine which are multiples of $81$, and found that (besides $4536$, already eliminated) only $5346$ is; thus the answer is $21$.

Comment: In the question it mentions that $9$ divides each factor. What does that mean ? What is factor here ?

Comment: @lsp, it's a multiplication problem. There are two factors and a product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $a,b,c$ for the sums of each of the three rows. We have $a+b+c=1+\cdots+9=45$. The fact that each row is a multiple of 9 means  that $a,b,c\in\{9,18,27,36\}$. So $a,b,c$ are either $27,9,9$ or $18,18,9$, in some order. As $1+2+3+4=10$, the 4-digit term cannot be $9$, so it is $18$ or $27$. But $27$ is not the sum of four consecutive integers, so the third row is $3,4,5,6$ in some order.

We are left with $1,2,7,8,9$ for the other two rows, one adding to $18$ and the other $9$. We cannot reach $18$ with two digits at all or with three digits not using the $9$, so the first row is necessarily one of the following two possibilities: $9,8,1$ in some order, and the middle one $2,7$; or $2,7,9$ in some order and $1,8$. This last case is easily discarded since the only 4-digit product is $279\times18=5022$, which produces the wrong last row.

Looking at the first row,  the last digit cannot be $1$ because that would imply a repeated digit. $2$ and $9$ do not fit, because they would put an $8$ in the last row. Actually, if the first row starts with $8$ or $9$, as $819\times27$ already  has five digits, we learn that the first number starts with $1$ and that the second one is $27$.

We have $189\times27=5103$, not good, so it has to be $198\times 27=5346$. So the answer to the question is $8+7+6=21$.